# Getting started with sn1per scanning

Tags: tools

I just pulled down the repository for an elite penetration testing tool call `sn1per` I want to use this tool to scan a list of websites. My goal is to automate the steps of a manual penetration test.

The steps to reach the point where I am at is to install the Ubuntu application on Windows 10. Then run the commands from the getting started guide from github:
https://github.com/1N3/Sn1per

```
git clone https://github.com/1N3/Sn1per
cd Sn1per
bash install.sh
```

Then run

```
sudo sniper security.stackexchange.com
```

The result is

```
Unknown scan option security.stackexchange.com...refer to the help menu for usage details.
```

Comment: "refer to the help menu for usage details" - did you do this?

Comment: This is not a security question. This is a "how do I access the help menu in this script?" question.

Comment: Do not use an "offensive security framework" on sites where you do not have specific, explicit, and written permission to test. It's a good way to get arrested.

Answer (score 4):

The first step to becoming an "elite pentester" - as you phrase it - is to be able to read error messages. The error message you see is that it says "Unknown scan option security.stackexchange.com". That means that it tries to interpret the string `security.stackexchange.com` as an option, rather than a target.

It also conveniently lists the necessary remediation step: `refer to the help menu for usage details`. The help menu referenced can be shown by calling `sniper -h` or `sniper --help` and will print the following:

> ```
> [*] NORMAL MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET>
>
> [*] NORMAL MODE + OSINT + RECON
> sniper -t <TARGET> -o -re
>
> [*] STEALTH MODE + OSINT + RECON
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m stealth -o -re
>
> [*] DISCOVER MODE
> sniper -t <CIDR> -m discover -w <WORSPACE_ALIAS>
>
> [*] SCAN ONLY SPECIFIC PORT
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m port -p <portnum>
>
> [*] FULLPORTONLY SCAN MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -fp
>
> [*] WEB MODE - PORT 80 + 443 ONLY!
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m web
>
> [*] HTTP WEB PORT MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m webporthttp -p <port>
>
> [*] HTTPS WEB PORT MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m webporthttps -p <port>
>
> [*] HTTP WEBSCAN MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m webscan 
>
> [*] ENABLE BRUTEFORCE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -b
>
> [*] AIRSTRIKE MODE
> sniper -f targets.txt -m airstrike
>
> [*] NUKE MODE WITH TARGET LIST, BRUTEFORCE ENABLED, FULLPORTSCAN ENABLED, OSINT ENABLED, RECON ENABLED, WORKSPACE & LOOT ENABLED
> sniper -f targets.txt -m nuke -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS>
>
> [*] MASS PORT SCAN MODE
> sniper -f targets.txt -m massportscan
>
> [*] MASS WEB SCAN MODE
> sniper -f targets.txt -m massweb
>
> [*] MASS WEBSCAN SCAN MODE
> sniper -f targets.txt -m masswebscan
>
> [*] MASS VULN SCAN MODE
> sniper -f targets.txt -m massvulnscan
>
> [*] PORT SCAN MODE
> sniper -t <TARGET> -m port -p <PORT_NUM>
>
> [*] LIST WORKSPACES
> sniper --list
>
> [*] DELETE WORKSPACE
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> -d
>
> [*] DELETE HOST FROM WORKSPACE
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> -t <TARGET> -dh
>
> [*] GET SNIPER SCAN STATUS
> sniper --status
>
> [*] LOOT REIMPORT FUNCTION
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> --reimport
>
> [*] LOOT REIMPORTALL FUNCTION
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> --reimportall
>
> [*] LOOT REIMPORT FUNCTION
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> --reload
>
> [*] LOOT EXPORT FUNCTION
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> --export
>
> [*] SCHEDULED SCANS
> sniper -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS> -s daily|weekly|monthly
>
> [*] USE A CUSTOM CONFIG
> sniper -c /path/to/sniper.conf -t <TARGET> -w <WORKSPACE_ALIAS>
>
> [*] UPDATE SNIPER
> sniper -u|--update
> ```

The very first option, aptly named "Normal Mode" shows that you call it by specifying the `-t` flag. Thus, the correct way to calling the tool is `sniper -t security.stackexchange.com`

## A word of warning...

As an elite pentester, you should be aware of two things:

1. The script is asking you to run it as root. In fact, it will refuse to run as anything but root. Did you check the contents of the script before running it? Or do you want to give anyone with a project with a catchy name permission to run their code on your machine as root?
2. You explicitly specify `security.stackexchange.com` as your target. I don't know if this is a placeholder or not, but in case it is not, be aware that "pentesting" a machine you do not own or have explicit permission to test **is illegal in many jurisdictions**. If you would like to set up a target to hone your elite pentesting skills on, I highly recommend setting up a virtual machine with [DVWA](https://dvwa.co.uk/) or [OWASP JuiceShop](https://owasp.org/www-project-juice-shop/).